# need help in python list

Tags: python, data-structures, hyperlink, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list in python. However my insert operation is giving the error below. Can any one help in fixing this ? My list will have head as the first node. Subsequent nodes will be appended in insert operation.

output:

```
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z.py", line 45, in <module>
    list_mgmt()
  File "z.py", line 43, in list_mgmt
    ll.display()
  File "z.py", line 32, in display
    print current.get_data()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
       self.nextnode = None

   def get_data(self):
       return self.data

   def get_nextnode(self):
       return self.nextnode

   def set_nextnode(self, node):
       self.nextnode = node

class LinkList:
   def __init__(self):
       self.head = None

   def insert(self, data):
       if self.head == None:
          current = Node(data)
          self.head = current
       else:
          current = self.head
          while current.get_nextnode() is not None:  
              current = current.get_nextnode
          current.set_nextnode(Node(data))

   def display(self):
       current = self.head
       while current is not None:
          print current.get_data()
          current = current.get_nextnode

   #def delete(self, data):
   #def size(self):
   #def search(self, data):

def list_mgmt():
    ll = LinkList()
    ll.insert(10)
    ll.insert(20)
    ll.display()

list_mgmt()
```

Comment: Why implementing a linked list in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
current = current.get_nextnode
```

You're missing parenthesis meaning "call that function", here your're just binding the function to the `current` variable, leading obviously to the next `'function' object has no attribute 'get_data'`.